# unwanted email footer spacing in Outlook

Tags: html, outlook, email-client

I've set up an html email footer which works fine when i test by adding into my email through Mail on a Mac. 
When I try to add via Outlook 2010 I get some unwanted spaces between table rows it seems.

[image]

The code is below, please could anyone advise how to change?, I have tried a lot of inline styles but nothing seems to alter these gaps.

```
<table id="Table_01" width="600" height="225" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="font-size:8px; text-align:center; font-family:Verdana; color:#ec008a; line-height: 10px; padding: 10px; background-color: #ffffff">
         <p style="font-weight:normal; font-size:18px; line-height:1.5em; color:#333 ">Please have a look at our brand new digital website.. <a style="color:#ec008a; font-size:21px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline" href="http://www.comapny.net" >www.comapny.net</a></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        <a href="http://www.comapny.net"><img src="http://www.comapny.net/html-email-footer/top-new.png" width="600" height="54" alt=""></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.comapny.net/html-email-footer/left.png" width="10" height="112" alt=""></td>
        <!--side shadow-->

    <td style="padding: 5px 10px; background-color: #ffffff; width:398px; font-family:Verdana; font-size:10px" valign="top" >
        <p style="margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><span style="font-size:13px; font-weight: bold; color: #000">xxx xxx</span></p>
            <span style="color:#ec008a">Position:</span> Sales Executive<br/>
            <span style="color:#ec008a">Email:</span> xxx@xxx <br/>
            <span style="color:#ec008a">Mobile:</span>  07903 147070 | <span style="color:#ec008a">Tel:</span> 01952 585585<br/>
            <a style="color:#000" href="http://www.comapany.net">www.comapany.net</a> <br />
            <a style="color:#000" href="http://www.comapny.net">www.comapny.net</a>           
        </td>
    <td style="width:142px; padding:0 10px; font-family:Verdana; font-size:10px"  >
        <img style="float:right" src="http://www.comapany.net/html-email-footer/contact_james_denning.jpg" ><!--<img src="images/PCP-EMAIL-FOOTER_PETRA-GALLOWAY-02_04.png" width="262" height="112" alt="">--></td>


       <!--side shadow-->  
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.comapany.net/html-email-footer/right.png" width="10" height="112" alt=""></td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.comapany.net/html-email-footer/left.png" width="10" height="112" alt=""></td>
        <!--side shadow-->

    <td valign="top" width="680" style="font-size:8px; font-family:Verdana; color:#696969; line-height: 10px; padding: 10px; background-color: #ffffff" colspan="2">
                    <span style="font-size:10px;">PCP Ltd &bull; Haddress</span><br/><br/>
                    This message is confidential. It may also be privileged or otherwise protected by work product immunity or other legal rules. If you have received it by mistake, please let us know by e-mail reply and delete it from your system; you may not copy this message or disclose its contents to anyone. Please send us by fax any message containing deadlines as incoming e-mails are not screened for response deadlines. The integrity and security of this message cannot be guaranteed on the Internet.

        </td>


       <!--side shadow-->  
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.comapny.net/html-email-footer/right.png" width="10" height="112" alt=""></td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        <img src="http://www.comapny.net/html-email-footer/bottom.png" width="600" height="17" alt=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding style="display:block;" and border="0" to all images in every email you create. Ever.
Fingers crossed that should fix it but give us an update of what you see if not.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will keep those additions in mind for future.

I was pushed for time so went back to the drawing board and recreated the table with less rows and cells and it seems OK in this case.